# Add a character before and after a specifc character

Tags: notepad++

I need to add a " after and before a comma, ie.

```
Hello, World
```

will become

```
Hello"," World
```

From what I see, I cannot figure out how to do this with Notepad ++
If this is not possible, which program can do this? (I cannot use anything online due to the file I have being 1 million some lines.)

Answer (score 4):

Do a find and replace in Notepad++, open it with `ctrl + h` .

For the find field, enter `,` and for replace enter `","`.

Answer (score 0):

With Notepad ++ is possible do what do you need and more :D

1. Click on menu bar "Search"
2. Click on "Replace... Ctrl + h "
3. Type in "Find what"  `,`
4. Type in  "Replace with `","`
5. Click on "Replace All"
6. Enjoy

Regards :D